# Disableing or work around the gravity of characterController.SimpleMove

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im a beginner and studying game creation, we are using Unity and we are working on a game for this semester. I have a planet with custom gravity for my player to walk around. In class, we wrote a PlayerController for our game, which is not quite compatible with the scripts/idea i have. My only problem is, we are using:

"characterController.SimpleMove"
which applies gravity to my character. I cant seem to find a way to work around this gravity or disable it outright. If i use "Move" instead of "SimpleMove", gravity is disabled, but the movement is way worse and im not really capable of rewriting the movement scripts myself as of right now. Is there an alternative to this, maybe a simpler way to disable or work around this gravity?

Disableing gravity in the project settings would work, but this would also effects my other scripts which uses gravity to create a custom gravity for my planet.

Is there a simple way to work around or disable the gravity in "characterController.SimpleMove"?

If my scripts or any other information is needed for tips, solutions etc. please let me know! Thank you so much in advance <3